# NSPageController tutorial for Cocoa on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to use `NSPageController` in some project but I have no idea how it works, does anybody have  time for some simple tutorial to show me because the documentation isn't helping me.

Forgot to mention: I'm working on `Mac project` (**NOT** `iOS`)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Simple NSPageController book mode tutorial

Create new **Cocoa Application**-project. Open `MainMenu.xib` in interface builder and add **Image Well** and **Label** objects to your application window. Also add **Page Controller** object.

[image]

Set **Page Controller's** view to point **Image Well**.

[image]

---

## Add some images to `Images.xcassets`

I used three images in this sample project:

- first.png
- second.png
- third.png

---

## MyAppDelegate.h

Add referencing outlets for **Page Controller**, **Label** and **Image Well**. Set `MyAppDelegate` as `NSPageControllerDelegate` and add also `NSArray` for images. After this your `MyAppDelegate.h` file should look like this:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSPageControllerDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSPageController *pageController;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *infoLabel;

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *imageArray;

@end
```

---

## MyAppDelegate.m

Some initialization:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    _imageArray = @[ [NSImage imageNamed:@"first"],
                     [NSImage imageNamed:@"second"],
                     [NSImage imageNamed:@"third"]];
    
    /* Set delegate for NSPageControl */
    [_pageController setDelegate:self];
    /* Set arranged objects for NSPageControl */
    [_pageController setArrangedObjects:_imageArray];
    /* Set transition style, in this example we use book style */
    [_pageController setTransitionStyle:NSPageControllerTransitionStyleStackBook];
    
    /* Set info label's text */
    NSString *info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image %ld/%ld", ([_pageController selectedIndex]+1), [_imageArray count]];
    [_infoLabel setStringValue:info];
}
```

Page Controller delegate methods:

```
- (void)pageController:(NSPageController *)pageController didTransitionToObject:(id)object {
    /* When image is changed, update info label's text */
    NSString *info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image %ld/%ld", ([_pageController selectedIndex]+1), [_imageArray count]];
    [_infoLabel setStringValue:info];
}

- (NSString *)pageController:(NSPageController *)pageController identifierForObject:(id)object {
    /* Returns object's array index as identiefier */
    NSString *identifier = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[_imageArray indexOfObject:object]] stringValue];
    return identifier;
}

- (NSViewController *)pageController:(NSPageController *)pageController viewControllerForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    /* Create new view controller and image view */
    NSViewController *vController = [NSViewController new];
    NSImageView *iView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[_imageView frame]];
    
    /* Get image from image array using identiefier and set image to view */
    [iView setImage:(NSImage *)[_imageArray objectAtIndex:[identifier integerValue]]];
    /* Set image view's frame style to none */
    [iView setImageFrameStyle:NSImageFrameNone];
    
    /* Add image view to view controller and return view controller */
    [vController setView:iView];
    return vController;
}
```

---

## And it's done

[image]
[image]

---

## If your _pageController is null/nil

Connect your Page Controller to _pageController by pressing `ctrl` and dragging with mouse to _pageController in `MyAppDelegate.h` file.

[image]

Comment: Not getting this to work. I suspect it is something to do with how the images have been added. I just dragged them from the finder to the xcasset. NSlog shows the images in the array. But the _pageController returns Null when I check it's arrangedObjects..

Comment: @markhunte I added images to .xcassets using Import..., if it matters, from popup menu when clicked with second mouse button in assets content list

Comment: @markhunte Is _pageController nil? Added Page Controller to your .xib file and created reference outlet?

Comment: [_pageController setArrangedObjects:_imageArray];
NSLog(@" _pageController  %@",_pageController.arrangedObjects); returns _pageController  (null)

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", _pageController); returns what?

Comment: (null). Meaning it is not being added?  and NSlog of [_imageArray count] returns 3

Comment: Ah, I just realised I had a typo in the Page Controllers name after I had hooked it up and corrected it forgetting to re hook it back. you summarisation was correct. Thanks for the tutorial. I actually only wanted to test this so I could vote you up. So now I can.

Comment: Hello, I followed your code, although I wrote it in Swift. But how do you control the pages? After I test your example the pages are not draggable so they don't move from one to another.

Comment: @juniperi what would the changes if we want to use history mode with pagecontroller. I am having a hard time finding an example for it