# Replicating Preview image viewing with NSPageController

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Thanks to Apple's [PictureSwiper sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PictureSwiper/Introduction/Intro.html) and the very nice [NSPageController tutorial from juniperi  here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801513/nspagecontroller-tutorial-for-cocoa-on-os-x), it's pretty easy to get tantalizing close to image viewing capabilities in Preview. Specifically I want to replicate the ability to swipe forwards/backwards between images/pages, use pinch-to-zoom resize the images, gesture to rotate the images/pages, and support two-page mode.

But there are some hurdles that make me wonder if NSPageController is the right approach or if it is too limiting and a custom view controller is needed.

1) Images of varying sizes are simply displayed stacked and if the top/upper layer image is smaller, the underlying image(s) show through. Using the same images in preview, they hide the larger "underlying" images/pages and fade the underlying image in/out with the swipe transition. I could hide underlying images by linking the page controller to the view rather than the image cell (like PictureSwiper), but that causes the entire view to scale on pinch to zoom and overall looks clunky.

2) Is it possible to use NSPageController with more than one image cell, e.g. two-page mode?

3) Is page/image rotation possible with NSPageController?

4) Is it possible to lock the zoom level for all the images, so they are uniformly displayed as navigated?

My apologies if this too general of a question, but the gist is whether NSPageController too limited and problematic to extend which would necessitate building a custom controller from scratch.

Thanks.

Comment: In the event you decide to roll your own, you'll probably want to use `-trackSwipeEventWithOptions:dampenAmountThresholdMin:max:usingHandler:` to get the same swipe interaction.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that used in a similar app but it had issues with finicky swipe recognition. Any vertical movement canceled the swipe. Probably a implementation/tuning issue but more reason why the NSPageController solution is so compelling. Just not sure how fragile/limited it is for extending.

Comment: Does anyone have an archived copy of v1.0 of Apple's PictureSwiper sample code? (Link above is for the current version 1.1). 

It predates NSPageController per the included ReadMe. I'm curious how they implemented it without NSPageController.

Comment: The v1.0 PictureSwiper code was part of Session 115 of WWDC 2011: [Scrolling, Swiping, Dragging: Now with more animation!](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011-115/). This version has a lot more of the logic needed for these fluid swiping transitions before they stripped it down reimplementing with NSPageController for WWDC 2012. It was available back then if anyone still has it. I can't find where Apple has the older version hosted.